# Access joined superclass objects inside query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've got a working joined table inheritance.

- **Abstract Superclass:** Person
- **Subclasses:** Parent and Child

Inside the ChildRepository I'd like to make a query which references to an object inside the Person class.

Person.php:

```
<?php
[...]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private User $user;

[...]
```

When I fetch all Children via findAll() for example, I can get their User objects, so the join works (the User object is the user who created this database entry).
Now I want to count the number of children a user has created:

Inside ChildrenRepository.class:

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

        return $qb
            ->select('count(c.id)')
            ->where('c.user.id = :userid')
            ->setParameter('userid', $userId)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Shouldn't this work? Currently, for this to work, I'm doing a manual join inside the query builder, but I don't think it's necessary. Or doesn't doctrine automatically resolve the joins on the query builder level?

Error is:

> Class App\Entity\Child has no field or association named user.id

Edit: What I could probably also do is to include the plain $id_user inside the Person.class. But since the object is already there, I didn't do this in any entity class. If it's a good practice, I'll do that. Gets rid of the join at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use more than one level of nesting (`child.user.id`) in your DQL field name (except embedabbles), you have to do `->join('child.user', 'user')` first and then reference `user.id`.

But in case of an id, you don't have to mention the `.id` part at all and use just `->where('c.user = :userId')`.

It's because the `user_id` column is already present in the `person` table and the join isn't needed from the SQL perspective.